# Sharepoint Migration tool from File Share to Sharepoint (Teams)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

This morning we completed a test migration of information from our File Share to SharePoint (Teams) using the free Microsoft SharePoint online tool.

However once all the documents migrated all of the metadata isn't pulling through correctly.

On the File Share we have a document called 'Names' if we check the properties it's created by a specific persons name (as we would expect) but after the migration on the SharePoint list this is appearing as created by BUILTIN\Administrator, this isn't happening for all of the documents within the SharePoint List a good lot of them are correct and are displaying the right created by names.

Having these documents appear as BUILTIN\Administrator isn't ideal Would anyone know how we resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario occurs that the special user not mapping correctly in Azure AD,files were assigned the default permission of the location to which it has been migrated in SPO.

Have you configured Azure AD sync and choose look up user in Azure AD in SPMT settings?

By default, Azure AD lookup is used to map users when submitting migration jobs. If you want to use your own mapping file, select the file to be used by selecting Choose file. By doing so, if a user isn't found in the mapping file, the tool won't look it up in AAD.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/spmt-settings

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-migration-tool-from-file-share-to/1ad9d30c-b2c0-4cb9-9842-a8d6cf4010ef